# sybase - update column to be identity, ordered by certain values

Tags: sql, sybase, identity, asa

I want to update the sequence column below to be an IDENTITY column in future, and the current rows must be updated to be ordered by update_time ascending.

How do I do this in Sybase? Simplified example of what I have below.

Current table:

```
SEQUENCE | UPDATE_TIME | DATA  
null     | 2016-01-01  | x
null     | 2013-01-01  | y
null     | 2015-01-01  | z
```

Desired table:

```
SEQUENCE | UPDATE_TIME | DATA  
3        | 2016-01-01  | x   
1        | 2013-01-01  | y
2        | 2015-01-01  | z
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this by joining the table onto itself but with 1 additional ID row. This additional row is created using the ROW_NUMBER function by ordering the update_time ascending. Something like...

UPDATE myTable SET update_seq = tmp.ID 
FROM myTable a INNER JOIN (
SELECT update_time, data, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY update_seq ASC) as ID     from myTable tmp
on a.update_time = tmp.update_time
and a.data = tmp.data

Answer (score 0):

On Sybase ASA you can numerate column using that update:

```
update [table_name]
set [SEQUENCE]=number(*)
order by [UPDATE_TIME]
```